# Are questions about a marijuana garden allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

Given the fact that it is legal to grow in some states should questions regarding growing marijuana be allowed?

Comment: "legal in some states" do you mean some countries or some parts of the United States?

Comment: For future reference: asking "are questions on *X* allowed?" without providing an example of a *real*, **good** question on *X* is a great way to get *X* excluded before it was ever really even on the table... (Use this information for good or evil as you see fit)

Comment: see also this:  [What is the policy on questions regarding generally illegal activity?](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-policy-on-questions-regarding-generally-illegal-activity)

Comment: Possibly legal in some states is a state jurisdiction option, however, FEDERAL law will always supersede state law and the FEDERAL law is that Marijuana is an illegal crop and a controlled substance. Even just discussing it is just inviting a watchful eye and potential pitfalls.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Our servers are in New York, US, where growing marijuana is illegal. We could get subpoena'd for your information and we'd be forced to give the authorities whatever they asked for.  So while our audience is most definitely global, our company and corporation is not.

I don't really think talking about growing marijuana is actually illegal, but I'm not sure you want to start attracting people that were interested in that particular topic because their overlap with expert gardeners and landscapers is minimal.

Given that you could ask pretty much any gardening aspect of marijuana growing question you wanted without actually talking about marijuana (hydroponics on topic, lighting on topic, etc), I think this community would be best served by deciding it's off topic.

Comment: US federal law prohibits [*the use, possession, sale, cultivation, and transportation of cannabis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_cannabis_by_U.S._jurisdiction), therefore there is nothing illegal about the **discussion** of cannabis cultivation. This should be a non-issue. There should even be a "cannabis" tag in the gardening stackexchange.

Comment: No. It's not solely about what's legal/illegal as much as who we're aiming to help on/attract to this site.

Comment: @J.Musser Anybody who has a legitimate question regarding gardening with cannabis should get a legitimate answer. It is gardening by definition. If you mark legitimate gardening questions as off-topic because you don't like what someone is gardening, you're just being an elitist at this point. 14% of the US states have legalized recreational cannabis. A majority of states have some form of legal cannabis(only 22 prohibit outright). You guys are all intentionally missing out on a chance to spread knowledge and learn. This is just sad for a stack exchange community.  Shame.

Comment: The law has changed since this answer was written: https://cannabis.ny.gov/adult-use and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_cannabis_by_U.S._jurisdiction