# Are legal questions on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

The only previous discussions I can find about legal questions here are ones asking about questions involving growing illegal plants/drugs.

- [Are questions about a marijuana garden allowed?](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-questions-about-a-marijuana-garden-allowed?s=1|0.1799)
- [What is the policy on questions regarding generally illegal activity?](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-policy-on-questions-regarding-generally-illegal-activity)

But what I would like to clarify, is whether or not questions asking about legal matters involving plants are on-topic or not.

For example a question asked last year about what is needed to ship plants in the US:

- [Are phytosanitary certificates needed to ship a plant within a state?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9195/are-phytosanitary-certificates-needed-to-ship-a-plant-within-a-state)

And a closed, question about the US State laws regarding growing a plant:

- [What is the legality of growing San Pedro cacti in Florida?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/17820/what-is-the-legality-of-growing-san-pedro-cacti-in-florida)

And a question about the **availability** of an herbicide in one US state:

- [Why is triclopyr not available in California?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8968/why-is-triclopyr-not-available-in-california)

Are legal questions on-topic here?

Answer (score 3):

Great question! There is no point in asking questions about interpretation of aspects of the law:

- laws regarding plants change from city to state/province to country.
- plant laws are often part of overlapping jurisdictions at any level of government.  For example:  Food and Drug department says yes, Agriculture says no, Environment is not sure
- plant laws change and answers become outdated.  Marijuana laws are an example of this.

With legal questions the answer usually seems to be "It depends". This does not make a good topic to be answered if the objective is a definitive answer that has enduring value.